# Get number of orders per customer

Tags: magento-1, customer, collection, sales-order

I've to filter `from`, `to` and multiple customer in sales order.

I don't have customer id's, so first I'm taking them using following code:

```
$customer_ids = array();
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));

foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
    array_push($customer_ids, $order->getCustomerId());
}

foreach ($customer_ids as $customer_id) {
    $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
        ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id);
    $_orderCnt = $orders->count(); //orders count
    echo "Customer ID : " . $customer_id . " Order Count : ". $_orderCnt. "<br>";
}
```

Above code is used to find how many orders have been placed by customers during selected time period.

I've used following code to not load collection in foreach but it's not working.

```
foreach ($customer_ids as $customer_id) {
    $temp = $orders;
    $temp->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',$customer_id);
    $_orderCnt = $temp->count(); //orders count
    echo "Customer ID : " . $customer_id . " Order Count : ". $_orderCnt. "<br>";
    unset($temp);
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can optimize the code without loading collection everytime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate));
$array = array_count_values($orders->getColumnValues('customer_id'));

foreach ($array as $customerId => $orderCount) {
    echo "Customer ID : " . $customerId . " Order Count : ". $orderCount. "<br>";
}
```

**Explanation:**

This stores `customer_id` for all orders in an array ...

```
$orders->getColumnValues('customer_id')
```

... and `array_count_values` sums same array values and stores it as array again.

**Edit:**

If you have orders, where `customer_id` is `null` then `array_count_values` gives an error *(Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!)*.

So you have to replace `null` first:

```
$array = array_count_values(array_map(function($v) {
    return (is_null($v)) ? "?" : $v;
}, $orders->getColumnValues('customer_id')));
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks very much @sv3n, Learned new thing :)